# Batch file to run command line on all files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a command line that I want to run on all zip files in a folder one by one. The command line is

```
"C:\ZereneStacker\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -Xmx10000m -DjavaBits=64bitJava -Dlaunchcmddir="C:\Users\dance621\AppData\Roaming\ZereneStacker" -classpath "C:\ZereneStacker\ZereneStacker.jar;C:\ZereneStacker\JREextensions\*" com.zerenesystems.stacker.gui.MainFrame "I:\Test\Zerene Batch Test\Raw\xxxxx.zip" -noSplashScreen
```

so xxxxx.zip changes depending on file name.

I think the bath file should look something like this but can not get it to work.

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do echo commandline_here_with "I:\Test\Zerene Batch Test\RAW\%%f"
```

So it would be in full..

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\') do echo "C:\ZereneStacker\jre\bin\javaw.exe" -Xmx10000m -DjavaBits=64bitJava -Dlaunchcmddir="C:\Users\dance621\AppData\Roaming\ZereneStacker" -classpath "C:\ZereneStacker\ZereneStacker.jar;C:\ZereneStacker\JREextensions\*" com.zerenesystems.stacker.gui.MainFrame "I:\Test\Zerene Batch Test\Raw\%%f" -noSplashScreen
```

The command line starts a program and closes it after it has processed the zip file and it would be nice if the batch waits until the first is complete before processing second

Any help would be great

Comment: The full command line does not start any command, it simply echoes a command line...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `/f` flag. It's as simple as

```
for %%f in (*.zip) do echo Your command goes here
```

For more details (pun intended), type `for /?` at a command prompt.